# Code practices: Comparing the view labels in codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf

OK open ended question!

So i have numorously stumbled upon a piece of code looks like this in my company. It's not best practice, but i see so often:

```
<RadioButton Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">商品标价签 85* 38mm</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">商品标价签 95* 38mm</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">单排40*30mm</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">双排40*25mm</RadioButton>
```

All is good but looking at the event handler i find a codesmell:

```
var obj = (string)radio.Content;
PaperSizeColumns = 1;
switch (obj.Trim())
{
    case "58mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "58";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "NaN";
        break;
    case "80mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "80";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "NaN";
        break;
    case "商品标价签 85* 38mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "85";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "38";
        break;
    case "商品标价签 95* 38mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "80";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "38";
        break;
    case "单排40*30mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "40";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "30";
        break;
    case "双排40*22mm":
        DocumentWidth.Text = "85";
        DocumentHeight.Text = "23";
        PaperSizeColumns = 2;
        break;
}
```

I could probably come up a dozen of reasons this is bad idea. But i can hardly argue that this a pretty darn fast approach and requires almost zero setup other than a few radio boxes and you're good to go.

I am thinking about a better way to do this. My first guess would be to set the DataContext, but it's dynamically typed and hardly solves the issue of maintainability.

So what is a good way of dealing with this, which i can teach my colleagues. Because if the workflow is too onerous he's just gonna ignore the advice.

Comment: Since this is working code it might be better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: I would probably go with XMLDataProvider. This will introduce them to 'proper' data objects or MVVM.

Comment: @CyberFox, can you give any feedback on my answer please? does it look better for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

possible approach:

step 1: declare a data item

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
}
```

step 2:

create a template for that data item and use that template in radioButtons. radioButtons have data items as their Content

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="E" DataType="local:Element">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource E}"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="ToggleButton_OnChecked"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <RadioButton>
        <local:Element Name="40*30mm" Width="40" Height="30" Columns="1"/>
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton>
        <local:Element Name="40*25mm" Width="40" Height="25" Columns="1"/>
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton>
        <local:Element Name="35*25mm" Width="35" Height="25" Columns="1"/>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

step 3:

use data item when handle Checked event

```
private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rdo = sender as RadioButton;
    Element x = rdo.Content as Element;
    // do smth with selected Element
}
```